# Pass unlock credentials to powershell script

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, vpn, group-policy, powershell

I have a powershell script that is run as a scheduled task and is triggered to run "On workstation unlock". The script is programmed to reconnect an SSTP VPN connection if the connection becomes disconnected during the time the workstation is locked. I would like to pass the username and password to the script so that the user is not prompted to enter the same information twice (once for the workstation unlock then again for the VPN connection) The domain username and pass are the same as the vpn username and pass.
The [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() will not let me access the password of the currently logged in user. Is there another way??

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no way from a standard user-mode process (like Powershell) to get the current user's clear text password.  And that's a good thing.  If there were, it would be a pretty large security vulnerability.

While it might be possibly to write a [Windows Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that can hook into the WinLogon APIs and ultimately receive the user's clear text username and password during the unlock process, it's really not the right solution for what you're trying to accomplish.  It's also probably beyond the level of programming effort you're willing to delve into for this solution.

If your VPN solution is actually integrated with your domain, I would hope it supports a way to use the user's existing Kerberos ticket to establish the VPN connection without actually needing to explicitly enter the user's credentials again.  That's going to be entirely dependent on your VPN solution though.  It also assumes the VPN solution is actually tied into your domain and not just using a duplicate identity s

Comment: I was thinking the same as far as how much of a vulnerability that would be if I could!! The VPN server is simply RRAS running on a W2K8 machine. I am using NPS to authenticate users contained in a group. The clients connect using the native windows VPN connection client/wizard. The problem is that I am using rasdial in my script and I am not familiar with a way to authenticate using anything other than cleartext. Is there another object in powershell that can pass kerberos tickets to RRAS to connect?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with RRAS at all. So I can't really help there. But I would think if it's all Windows end-to-end, there has to be a way to reuse the existing credentials.

Comment: My sentiments exactly!!

Comment: Not sure if I'm heading down the right path but, I enabled the "Store passwords using reversible encryption" GPO setting but have had no luck locating the stored location on the local machine. Is the only way to lookup the password to copy Group.xml from the location mentioned in this article?
http://obscuresecurity.blogspot.com/2012/05/gpp-password-retrieval-with-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

I use the two script to save and load credentials.
Only the user who saved the credential can load them.

Of course the user must enter his credential one time.

**Save-Credential.ps1**

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$CredentialName
    )

$path = (([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($PROFILE.CurrentUserCurrentHost))+ '\Credentials\'+$CredentialName+'.xml')
$dir = ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($path))
if((Test-Path ($dir)) -eq $false)
{
    New-Item -Path $dir -ItemType Directory
}

$cred = Get-Credential
$cred | Export-Clixml $path
```

**Load-Credential.ps1**

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$CredentialName
    )

$path = (([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($PROFILE.CurrentUserCurrentHost))+ '\Credentials\'+$CredentialName+'.xml')
if(Test-Path ($path ))
{
    Import-Clixml $path
}else
{
    Write-Host "File $path not found."
}
```

The credential object has a secure string property.